# Design question about Swing GUI updates via PropertyChangeSupport

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, properties, visitor-pattern

In the past I have used PCS to update Swing elements that displayed certain fields and everything worked as expected. However, I am now facing a relatively complex (in other words, terribly designed) UI that displays a lot of fields. Data updates come in bunches (a network packet containing new values for about 1,000 fields), and I was wondering what the proper way to handle something like this is.

My main concern is that whenever a data packet comes, 1,000 PropertyChangeEvents are triggered, causing 1,000 .repaint()'s (or .revalidate()'s or whatever). The more prudent way seemed to do something like "gui.stopRepainting(); fireAllThePropertyEvents(); gui.restartPainting();". Is there a way to do that, or is there maybe a better way to handle this ?

Comment: Have you confirmed that this has a performance impact?

Answer (score 3):

A repaint request is passed to the RepaintManager which in turn combines multiple requests into a single repaint.

I find it strange that you have 1000, fields of a single form. Assuming this in fact true then I doubt all 1000 will be visible at the same time. I believe the RepaintManager will only paint those that are visible so the overhead may not be as bad as you think.

I don't know of any way to stop the repaint, but maybe you could make the pane invisble, do the updates and then make it visible again.

Or maybe you can create a custom RepaintManager the does nothing. You instal it, do your updates and then reinstal the default manager.